# How can I modify my Caesar cipher implementation to output the result as a single string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I'm trying to write a Ceasar cipher; whenever it prints the result, each string creates a new line instead of a single string.

This is the output:

Q

M

D

X

I wanted the output to go like this: QMDX.

```
Here is the code:
print("""                                                             
           88             88                                 
           ""             88                                 
                          88                                 
 ,adPPYba, 88 8b,dPPYba,  88,dPPYba,   ,adPPYba, 8b,dPPYba,  
a8"     "" 88 88P'    "8a 88P'    "8a a8P_____88 88P'   "Y8  
8b         88 88       d8 88       88 8PP""""""" 88          
"8a,   ,aa 88 88b,   ,a8" 88       88 "8b,   ,aa 88          
 `"Ybbd8"' 88 88`YbbdP"'  88       88  `"Ybbd8"' 88          
              88                                             
              88                                      """)



alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

def encrypt(text, shift):
    for i in text:
        encryption = ""
        i_unicode = ord(i)
        i_index = ord(i) - ord('A')
        new_index = (i_index + shift) % 26
        new_unicode = new_index + ord('A')
        new_character = chr(new_unicode)
        encryption = encryption + new_character

        print(encryption)


            
        
        

encrypt(text, shift)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As a note: This can be implemented *much* more succinctly (and more efficiently to boot) with `str.maketrans` (called with slices based on the `shift`) to make the translation table, followed by a single call to `text.translate` using the resulting translation table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `encryption` outside the for loop. Right now it's value is being reset every time you encode a new letter, so it isn't getting any longer.

```
def encrypt(text, shift):
    encryption = ""
    for i in text:
        i_unicode = ord(i)
        i_index = ord(i) - ord('A')
        new_index = (i_index + shift) % 26
        new_unicode = new_index + ord('A')
        new_character = chr(new_unicode)
        encryption = encryption + new_character
        
        print(encryption)
```

This will result in:

```
Q
QM
QMD
QMDX
```

If you only want it to print once, put the `print` statement outside the for loop.

```
def encrypt(text, shift):
    encryption = ""
    for i in text:
        i_unicode = ord(i)
        i_index = ord(i) - ord('A')
        new_index = (i_index + shift) % 26
        new_unicode = new_index + ord('A')
        new_character = chr(new_unicode)
        encryption = encryption + new_character
        
    print(encryption)
```

Then it will output:

```
QMDX
```

In case this comes up for how to make a caeser cypher in python, a more efficient method is, as suggested by ShadowRanger, `string.maketrans`:

```
import string

def caeserEncode(target, shift):
    alphabet = \
        string.ascii_lowercase + \
        string.ascii_uppercase

    encodedAlphabet = \
        string.ascii_lowercase[shift:] + \
        string.ascii_lowercase[0:shift] + \
        string.ascii_uppercase[shift:] + \
        string.ascii_uppercase[0:shift]
    transTable = target.maketrans(alphabet, encodedAlphabet)
    return target.translate(transTable)

print(caeserEncode("testString", 2))
#output vguvUvtkpi

print(caeserEncode("abc xyz", 2))
#cde zab
```

Comment: Thank you! lol I actually lined up the print and for, but it didn't work.